# Google Sheets: Code.GS doesn't detect data refresh/fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Working with JIRA. Trying to fetch data and then run calculations. I am able to individually add up the cells =a1+b1 and get a result. When I tried =sum(); No results. A little bit of research led me to using =sumproduct() and that worked. My assumption from that was that it is now treating the data fetched from JIRA as an array.

Now I wanted to understand when we first fetched the data and populated the field and then subsequent refreshes so I know how fresh the data is.

I don't know if this is a consequence of what I was dealing with before I figured out the sumproduct() situation with adding everything up.

Any help would be amazing because I have been working on this for days and having difficulties.

The code below is the one that I am using in my code.gs and I picked it up from a YT video lol.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e){
  //variables 
  var startRow = 2;
  var targetColumn = 1;
  var ws = "APM";
  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){
    
    var currentDate = new Date();    
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).setValue(currentDate);
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,6).getValue() == ""){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,6).setValue(currentDate);
    } //END IF check if date created exists
  } //END IF check column, row, worksheet
} // END function addTimestampe
```

Comment: You question does not include any code/ explanation about how you fetch data from JIRA and where you perform the sumproduct. Do you fetch the data with an IMPORTRANGE() function within the spreadsheet? Or do you have an Apps Script for this?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. Atlassian has a JIRA sheets connector. I go to add ons and I just select it. 

Even without that I am provided the ability to call out a specific JQL query.

Comment: I tried to upload an image but it wouldn’t let me because I’m too new 

Comment: I am not sure how the issue with sum() and sumproduct() is related to this question, did I understand it correctly that your actual question is why your trigger does not fire when your data is refreshed? May I ask you how fetch your data? With a script or a cell formula? And which exactly?